# North American market Lego boxes sold in Europe (by Lego itself). Is that normal?

Tags: shopping, lego-group, packaging

Thanks to [this](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1901/why-does-lego-state-the-number-of-parts-on-us-boxes-but-not-in-europe) old question I know that North American market Lego boxes have the piece-count printed on the box, as that is a requirement in USA and Canada.
European market boxes don't have that.

However in the last 3 months I have purchased 2 Lego Creator boxes in The Netherlands (which is still Europe, as far as I know) that have the North America box style.
One box (the 1960's Mustang model) was bought January 2020 in a regular toy shop (not a Lego store). And I noticed several other sets in their shop with piece-counts on the box.
(So this could be a case of a retail chain sourcing their stock via unusual channels.)

But the other one (the Harley Fat Boy model) was bought middle of April 2020 directly from Lego on Lego.com and shipped from their German warehouse.

How common is this?
Some reasons come to mind:
Is this just a matter of Lego occasionally using packaging intended for the North American market to supplement their European packaging stock if that runs low?
Is Lego having production/stock issues due to Corona and is selling NA sets in Europe in stead of shipping them to NA?
Or is Lego starting to use a single box for all markets on some models? (The linked question is 7 years old. Things could have changed since then.)

Does anyone know?

Comment: It might be hard to answer, as we don't know what is TLG doing on their side. It could be one of the reasons you've mentioned. And I haven't seen US box in Eastern Europe for past 7 years.

Comment: On a related note, when the [Mandalorian battle packs](https://www.lego.com/en-ca/product/mandalorian-battle-pack-75267) came out, there were European boxes sold in our local Lego Store (in Canada) with stickers placed on showing the piece count.