# My copy of Republic Fighter tank 7679 doesn't have a part count. Is it legit?

Tags: star-wars

Oddly enough it has no part count on the box whatsoever and I bought it from a Italian seller on Bricklink. It was quite expensive. I doubt this is a counterfeit. But you can't be to sure. Why is there no part count? Is that a thing that happens with some LEGO sets?

[image]

Comment: Thank you gentleman for answering my queries. I'm glad.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does LEGO state the number of parts on US boxes, but not in Europe?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1901/why-does-lego-state-the-number-of-parts-on-us-boxes-but-not-in-europe)

Answer (score 5):

LEGO boxes in Europe do not have piece count on the front. There is no legal requirement within EU to present this information on packaging.

Actually, depending on where you live, it may be odder to see boxes *with* part count on its front.

Comment: Our local Lego store recently had boxes that had a piece count sticker added on, because the boxes had come from a region where it wasn't printed, but due to varying demand (I'd guess) got sent to a region where it normally would be.

Comment: why even have a separate print without? I cannot imagine it would cost more in ink, and it usually tends to cost more to have multiple prints that have to be managed etc

Comment: @htmlcoderexe World is not "US-centric". Living in Europe, where LEGO originally comes from, I guess, the question would sound like "Why have a separate print with? Just make it a sticker when needed". On a serious note, NA is different market where TLG use different printing facilities for sets produced in Mexico's factory and do not ship boxes from Europe.

Comment: I also live in Europe - I was thinking more along the lines that if they have to do it for one country where it is mandated, they might as well do it for all the countries especially since the information is semi-useful regardless of where you live. I assumed all lego was just shipped around from a single location more or less, though, so that explains it. I guess now I have to find out how it would be possible to have a similar regulation in Europe as usually we're the more restrictive ones ;)