# Do LEGO part counts on boxes include spare parts, brick separators and instruction manuals?

Tags: piece-information, sets

I bought some LEGO sets recently and was wondering (for no reason), if the part numbers that are shown on the outside of LEGO boxes include (along with the number of parts needed to build the set):

1. The number of spare parts,
2. The [brick separator](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=96874#T=C) (if one),
3. The instruction manual(s).

Comment: Found some information [here](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/1396/7638), and [here](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/853/7638).

Comment: As noted in another question (https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/9337/90), If the box set doesn't have a manual (or it gets lost), you can find a soft copy (PDF) version on Lego's site: https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. No. Set [30476](https://brickset.com/sets/30476-1/Happy-Turtle) (pictured below) says it contains 33 pieces, but [the set contains 3 extra pieces](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=30476-1) in addition to the ones needed to build the set. I believe it has always been this way.
2. Yes. When LEGO re-released the Taj Mahal, it contained exactly the same pieces except for the addition of a brick separator. The part count on the set's box was also increased by 1.
3. No, excluding the extra pieces, [30476](https://brickset.com/sets/30476-1/Happy-Turtle) (pictured below) has exactly the 33 plastic pieces the manual says it should have.

**Set [30476](https://brickset.com/sets/30476-1/Happy-Turtle):**

[image: set 30476]

Comment: Thank you for that detailed information! I did not know that BrickLink counted the different minifig body parts as one part.

Comment: Also - the piece count should match the piece count in the back of the manual - which doesn't include the spares, but does (usually) show the brick separator.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid Not to say you are wrong, but, I have looked at the back of many instruction manuals, and have never noticed the brick separator on there.

Comment: @WilliamV. I'm not sure if it all manuals have it, but I know some do. [70914-1: Bane Toxic Truck Attack has it listed](http://cache.lego.com/bigdownloads/buildinginstructions/6206124.pdf).

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid Okay, Thanks

Comment: Yeah, it's possible that some don't, but I have examples going back to at least Mindstorms RIS that do