# Lego identification help! Red torso, lightsaber handle, and grey pieces?

Tags: building, set-identification, sets, instructions, lego-group

What does this build? Can anyone help me with the instructions link?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the top left corner you can see the back of this torso:

[Torso SW Darth Maul Chest with Gray and Silver Collar and Belt Pattern / Printed Red Arms / Black Hands](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973pb1484c01#T=C&C=5)

[image]

So this is part of [75022-1: Mandalorian Speeder](https://brickset.com/sets/75022-1/Mandalorian-Speeder)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Syberion's answer and identification of the set, you can find many PDFs of manuals on Lego's site: https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions

You can search by the set number, theme, and/or year to find manuals.

For this specific set, here are the links:

- Search for set **75022** on Lego's Manual site ([link](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions/search#?search&text=75022%2520Mandalorian%25E2%2584%25A2%2520Speeder%2520Star%2520Wars%2520TM))
- Direct PDF link: https://lc-www-live-s.legocdn.com/bigdownloads/buildinginstructions/6050596.pdf