# Do extra parts add to set's resell value?

Tags: shopping, value, preservation

When I build a set I tend to keep the box and instructions as I noticed they add to the value of the set.

I also keep the extra parts in the box but I'm not so sure if they add actual value. My understanding is they are random so there is no way to confirm they are the original pieces that came with the set.

Is there any value in keeping them along with the set when selling?

UPDATE: Based on the comments I understand the extra parts are consistent and predictable. So I would have thought having extra parts in would make the set more valuable. In BrickLink generally the status of box, minifigs and instructions are mentioned. No mention of extra parts.

Am I correct to think it doesn't add value if we included extra parts?

Thanks.

Comment: Extra parts are not random and are the same for each copy of particular set. You can easily identify these parts on Bricklink.

Comment: Thanks @Alex. Before I posted I read this answer which says the extras are random: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/1396/9280. Also on BrickLink it says "Extra parts can vary depending on when and where a set was manufactured, meaning that some new sets may include them and others may not. " (source: https://www.bricklink.com/help.asp?helpID=1562#extraItems) so I'm confused now if they are the same or not.

Comment: This is not meant negatively, but Consumer Services is not a reliable source in this case, they just want to avoid complaints if a spare part is missing. In reality the selection of spare parts in a set is not only consistent among copies of the set, it is also predictable what they will be.

Comment: "Extra parts can vary depending on when and where a set was manufactured" This only means that there might be some sets, for which there is a variance. As in, you might be able to tell two copies of set #ABCDE apart based on the amount of extra parts, and conclude that one has been packaged in Mexico and the other in Hungary. For the vast majority of sets there is no such variance and the amount of extra parts is just as consistent as that of the base parts.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I've updated my post as I was mistaken about the extra parts being random.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, I think it doesn't add much value. But it depends.

Some sets, like US version of [8284](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8284-1), have extra parts crucial for alternative model (aka B-model). So unless you include them, you are selling incomplete set. The inclusion of all parts to build all models is part of "complete" condition description on [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/help.asp?helpID=102). Extra parts excluded though.

Then again, new DOTS sets, which have random printed tiles, but the number of included items is the same. So if you are looking for particular print, it would be nice to have extra.

Sure, there's a ton of sets with quite generic extra pieces, that you may already have a ton of. And buyer may as well already have a lot of them. However, buying a used set with box, instructions, stickers/sticker sheet as well as extra parts is always nice, especially if it is older set.